# Unicode symbol in Rails' view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to include a degree symbol into my Rails view. If I put the degree symbol (°) straight into .html.erb file, it is displayed by browser in a normal way.

But this symbol should be transferred to view via string. And here the problem begins.

If I put this:

```
<%= 176.chr %>
```

into view, or put

```
.... + 176.chr
```

into ruby source, I get

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

How to make Rails recognize all views as UTF-8 by default?

Comment: the non utf-8 thing isn't your view, it's that 176.chr, which defaults to ASCII-8BIT for values > 127. The single byte 176 isn't a valid utf-8 character either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use special replacement for this symbol in HTML: `&deg;`.

http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp

You have to put it in HTML, outside the <%= %>. Or use raw helper. Or mark it as html_safe. And by the way, did you try to supply encoding in your chr? Like `176.chr(__ENCODING__)` (`__ENCODING__` here isn't placeholder, it's Ruby thing) or 176.chr(Encoding::UTF_8). All these approaches should work.

Comment: Your reply would be right if we are talking about inserting a symbol into HTML source. But we are talking about getting this character from Ruby string and putting it into view's output.

Comment: It's much easier to remember, read and maintain `&deg;`-like symbols then their codes. Consider this as advice. Even if you've solved your problem, use entities instead of codes.

Comment: Ok, it seems that '&deg;'.html_safe does the trick, but I would like to be able in future to insert a character with arbitrary charcode.

Comment: You have to put it in HTML, outside the `<%= %>`. Or use `raw` helper. Or mark it as `html_safe`. And by the way, did you try to supply encoding in your `chr`? Like `176.chr(__ENCODING__)` (`__ENCODING__` here isn't placeholder, it's Ruby thing) or `176.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)`. All these approaches should work.

Comment: = myvar.to_s + 176.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) did the trick. Thank you. (But it is a little bit monstrous).

Comment: @jdoe That should be an answer in itself.

Answer (score 2):

This should already be specified inside your `application.rb` inside `/config/`.

The relevant section should look like this:

```
module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.                                                                                                                                     
    config.encoding = "utf-8"    
  end
end
```

I think the issue here is that you are generating a ASCII-8BIT character that should be inserted into the UTF-8 body.

If you want to use a UTF-8 String in your Ruby code you have to put this magic string into the first line of your ruby file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Details on Encoding in Ruby 1.9 can be found [here](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/)

Comment: config.encoding = "utf-8" is already there, # encoding: UTF-8 does not work.